# Ignorar código de erro http ao usar file_get_contents

Tags: php, http-status, file-get-contents

Estou usando `file_get_contents` para fazer uma requisição a uma url. Essa requisição pode retornar um erro `422`. Quando esse erro `422` é retornado, preciso capturar o corpo, que vem em formato `JSON`. Porém o `file_get_contents` parece não ser capaz de retornar o conteúdo quando a requisição retorna um código de erro.

A mensagem retornada é a seguinte:

> Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity

Quando esse  Warning é gerada, o `file_get_contents`retorna `FALSE`, mas preciso que ele retorne o conteúdo que é retornado pela url, mesmo que tenha código de erro.

Como faço para `file_get_contents` ignorar os erros e me retornar o conteúdo?

Por exemplo (usando o [httpbin.org](https://httpbin.org) pra retornar um erro de propósito):

```
 file_get_contents('https://httpbin.org/status/422')
```

Comment: tenta setar o Header manualmente pra 200 : `http_response_code(200)`

Comment: Isso aí não resolve o problema, @LucasQueirozRibeiro. Isso muda a resposta enviada, não a que eu recebo em file_get_contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira encontrada para resolver esse problema foi utilizando um `stream_context_create`.

Essa função pode criar um `context` para a função `file_get_contents` e assim podemos configurá-la para não gerar um *warning* caso ocorra algum código de status diferente de 200 na requisição.

É necessário definir um `array` com o valor `ignore_errors` como `TRUE`, dentro de `http`.

Veja:

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'ignore_errors' => true,
        'method'        => $method,
        'header'        => $headers
    ]
]);

$response = file_get_contents('https://httpbin.org/status/422', false, $context);
```

Com o código acima, quando o status for `422` (ou qualquer outro código de erro), ao invés de `file_get_contents` retornar `FALSE` e disparar um *Warning*, ela irá retornar a conteúdo retornado, idependente do código de status.

Se for necessário obter algum valor do header, você poderá usar a variável especial [`$http_response_header`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php)